# SQL find total count of each `dynamic` type in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have stored my record data on SQL server and I want to get what should be a simple query to get the total count of each type of my record. I have a table with the following pattern:

```
Id |  Type  | ID_Type |
-----------------------
1  |  Bags  |   B1    |
2  |  Shoes |   S1    |
3  |  Shoes |   S1    | 
4  |  Bags  |   B1    |  
..
```

The `Type` of my record is dynamic it's working like a category if the user added new Type like `Shirts` and created new record my query should also get the total of `Shirts`. Here's my sample data:

```
Id |   Type   | ID_Type |
------------------------
1  |   Bags   |   B1    |
2  |   Shoes  |   S1    |
3  |   Shoes  |   S1    | 
4  |   Bags   |   B1    |  
5  |  Shirts  |   S2    |
6  |  Shirts  |   S2    |
7  |  Shirts  |   S2    |
..
```

Below is the result I would like to get with total of records:

```
 Bags | Shoes | Shirts | Total |
-------------------------------
   2  |   2   |   3    |   7
```

Comment: If you don't have a static list of types, you either (a) need to use dynamic SQL or (b) need to just do a pivot in whatever application layer you have and do a regular `SELECT Type = ISNULL(Type, 'Total'), Cnt = COUNT(*) FROM mytable GROUP BY Type WITH ROLLUP;`

Comment: i have done same thing what you mentioned but currently i am unable to give you query..but the concept is that you need to use pivot but your pivoted column will be your dynamic type like categroies, you have to select the categories and store in variable and pass to pivot..same way you need to calculate the sum for each and an extra column of total..simple thing you can do with pivot but with  dynamically generated columns and their values.

Comment: @PSK nope, the answer you've provided helped me with the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create dynamic `PIVOT` like following. To generate the `Total` column you can simply use `WITH ROLLUP` in `GROUP BY`

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(max) = Stuff((SELECT DISTINCT ', ' + Quotename([Type]) 
             FROM   [YourTableName]
             FOR xml path(''), type).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'), 1, 1, '') + ',[Total]'; 

EXECUTE('SELECT * FROM (select ISNULL(type, ''total'') as Type,Count(*) n 
                   from  [YourTableName] GROUP BY [Type] WITH ROLLUP) s
                    PIVOT (max(n) FOR [Type] IN ('+@cols+') ) pvt')
```

[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/JIMK53537)

**Output**

```
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| Bags | Shirts | Shoes | Total |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
| 2    | 3      | 2     | 7     |
+------+--------+-------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can  do with case statement in this way.

```
with cte as (

Select 1 as ID, 'Bags'   as [Type] union all  
Select 2 as ID, 'Shoes'  as [Type] union all  
Select 3 as ID, 'Shoes'  as [Type] union all  
Select 4 as ID, 'Bags'   as [Type] union all 
Select 5 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type] union all 
Select 6 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type] union all 
Select 7 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type]  ) 

select count(case when [type] ='Bags' then ID end) Bags, count(case when [type] 
='Shoes' then ID end) Shoes , 
count(case when [type] ='Shirts' then ID end) Shirts, count(1) total  from cte;
```

Output:

```
 Bags   Shoes Shirts  total
  2      2     3       7
```

Using Dynamic SQL approach:

IF the columns are dynamic then you can achieve your results in this way.

Test Data:

```
 -- drop table #temp
Select 1 as ID, 'Bags'   as [Type] into #temp  union all  
Select 2 as ID, 'Shoes'  as [Type] union all  
Select 3 as ID, 'Shoes'  as [Type] union all  
Select 4 as ID, 'Bags'   as [Type] union all 
Select 5 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type] union all 
Select 6 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type] union all 
Select 7 as ID, 'Shirts' as [Type] 

--drop table #temp1
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by [Type] order by ID) Rownum  
into #temp1 from #temp 



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
@query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(c.Type) 
    FROM #temp c
    FOR XML PATH(''))  
,1,1,'')

 set @query = 'SELECT   '+@cols+' ,total  from 
    (
        select Type, ID, total 

            from #temp1  t  
            join (select count(1) total from #temp1) t1 on 1= 1 
   ) x
    pivot 
    (
         count(ID) 
        for Type in (' + @cols + ')
    ) p '

 Exec sp_executesql  @query

Output: 

Bags     Shirts Shoes total 
2         3      2     7
```

Comment: I have dynamic types, how can I set case when the types is can be changed or added new one?

Comment: Added query to handle the columns dynamically and get the output.